# In my Add to cart page , the product variant show only in static table, not showing in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

[i want output in product details column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSGLy.png) I want get all variant of product in dynamic way, but variant show only in static not dynamic. I want get all variant of product in dynamic way, but variant show only in static not dynamic.

I want to set dynamic data in this div:

```js
const productTitle = '<div id="product-description" name="id"> </div>'
```

**JS code:**

```js
function fetchCart() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/cart.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(cart) {
      if (cart.item_count === 0) {
        console.log("cart empty");
        // document.getElementById("cart-empty-message").innerHTML = ("Your cart Is Empty!");
      } 
      else {
        renderCart(cart);
        console.log(cart.total_price)
        document.getElementById("maintotal").innerHTML = cart.total_price
      }
    },
  });
}

var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  console.log(selector.product.variants)
}

new Shopify.OptionSelectors('product-description', {
  product: {
    {
      product | json
    }
  },
  onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
  enableHistoryState: true
});

function renderCart(cart) {
  clearCartDrawer();

  cart.items.forEach(function(item, index, selectCallback) {
    let a = item;
    const productImage = '<img class="ajax-cart-item__image" src="' + item.image + '" >';
    const productTitle = '<div id="product-description" name="id"> </div>';
    const productQuantity = '<div class="ajax-cart-item__quantity"> <div class="counter"><button class="down" data-id=' + item.id + ' onClick="decreaseCount(event, this)">-</button><input type="text" class="vln" value="' + item.quantity + '" min="0" /><button class="up" data-id=' + item.id + ' onClick="increaseCount(event, this)">+</button></div></div>'
    const productIcon = '<i data-id="' + item.variant_id + '" class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>'
    const productPrice = '<div class="ajax-cart-item__price">' + item.line_price + '</div>'
    const tbodyAppend = $('.mainpartclass').append('<tr> <td>' + productImage + '</td> <td>' + productTitle + '</td> <td>' + productQuantity + '</td><td>' + productIcon + '</td> <td>' + productPrice + '</td><tr>')
    tbodyEle = tbodyEle + tbodyAppend;
  });
}
```

Comment: How do you call `renderCart()`? Do you mean that you want it to render on a timer?

Comment: @showdev rendercart call form ajax through.This is my edited code.

Comment: From a quick check it looks like you've used `const` in the renderCart function when you needed to use `var`. Check if that works and I'll create an answer.

Comment: @Antony , thanks man but, its not working